# Android Studio 3.6.1 cannot resolve symbols

Tags: android, android-studio

Ever since I updated AS to 3.6 and then 3.6.1, every time I add a new string or a file or a drawable (basically anything accessible through resources) it throws a `cannot resolve symbol` error until I restart.

Is this a known issue with the latest release?

Comment: For me it's not happening. Try to clean and rebuild the project, if not then invalidate Caches/ Restart

Comment: I have the same problem. Cleaning, rebuilding, invalidating, restarting, closing and opening, solve the problem just for minutes. After changin or adding new names resources in layouts (basically), the problem ocurrs " again.". Today i have to restart about 30 times.... I try downgrade the Gradle, but the same problem. Its something whit 3.6.1

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall Studio will fix this problem